# check if object in array of objects - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know i have to use `some` but for some reason i cant seem to get it right. i have a collection in my mongodb database of posts. each post has an array of objects named "likes" that references the users that liked this post. so in my backend i want to check if the user exists in the likes array of the post. if it does not exist then like the post, else return with an appropriate message on my react frontend. The code i will include always returns false from `some` so a user can like a post infinite times.

```js
exports.postLike = async (req, res, next) => {
  const postId = req.query.postId;
  const userId = req.query.userId;


  console.log('postId: ' + postId);

  try{
    const post = await Post.findById(postId).populate('creator').populate('likes');
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!post.likes.some(post => post._id === user._id)){
      post.likes.push(user);
      console.log('liked a post');
      const result = await post.save();
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Post liked!', post: result });
    } else {
      console.log('Post already liked!');
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Post already liked!', post: post });
    }

  }catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }

};
```

i clearly haven't understood, yet, how `some` works so if you can help that would be great. also if you have any other solution that would be good in this case then please post it. i tried some random codes with indexOf and includes for checking but it didn't work either. i am not sure which is the right way to check if the user object is included in the "likes" array of objects. i would prefer not to write any function of my own to check this, i want to do it using an existing function/method provided by javascript.

Comment: What is `_id` ? Is it a string or a `MongoDB.ObjectId` ?

Comment: `MongoDB.ObjectId`

Comment: `likes` is in a separate collection correct?

Comment: no its just an object array in my posts collection that references the users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to offer a different route here. You are fetching all the data including a join to the creator and likes just to **add** a like to the collection. This is a little wasteful and can be achieved by just doing an `update` and use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) which will add the like **if it does not exist.**

You then just check `nModified` in the result to know if it was added or not. So you can have:

```
const result = await Post.updateOne(
    {
        id: 1
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            likes: {
                userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.userId)
            }
        }
    }
);

console.info(result.nModified === 1);
```

Alternatively, you can use `some` as follows using `===` to compare type and value:

```
posts.likes.some(like => like.userId.toString() === req.query.userId)
```

Comment: just a bit change in the names but thanks!! this actually worked. i will also check out the update option. seems like you have a really good point! 
`post.likes.some(like => like._id.toString() === userId)`

Comment: No prob, best of luck with the rest

Answer (score 1):

`MongoDB.ObjectId` is a wrapper around a primitve, just like `Number` or `Boolean`. And just like

```
  new Boolean(true) === new Boolean(true)
```

will be false, your comparison will fail too. You have to take out the primitive for comparison:

```
 post._id.valueOf() === user._id.valueOf()
```

Comment: `some` still returns always false

Comment: Are you sure that `post.likes` actually contains an entry with a matching `_id` ?

Comment: yes. i can see the object of the user reference in my database. in mongodb compass and i can also print and see the post.likes array of objects. both contain the user